# how to validate presence of element in absence of another in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have this model that validates `presence: true` for both  `post_id` and `user_id` but I want it to validate the presence of one if the other is absent.

here is the validation :

```
validates :user_id, :comment_id, :post_id, presence: true
```

If you have any questions don't hesitate to ask

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since ActiveRecord automatically creates question mark methods for each of your model's attributes, you could also do:

```
validates_presence_of :post_id, unless: :user_id?
validates_presence_of :user_id, unless: :post_id?
```

`:post_id?` or `user_id?` returns false for nil or blank.

Comment: I want to validate presence of user_id if post_id is not present so isn't it supposed to be validates_presence_of :post_id, unless: :user_id?

Comment: Yep, you're correct! Check my edited answer and let me know if it works for you :)

Answer (score 1):

```
validates_presence_of :post_id, unless: :user_id
validates_presence_of :user_id, unless: :post_id
```

Comment: you mean validates_presence_of :post_id, unless: :user_id because I want it to validate user_id if no post_id is present

Answer (score 0):

Simple Update thanks to rubocop, when i tried to use this logic, rubocop auto correct my line actually

C: [Corrected] Rails/Validation: Prefer the new style validations validates :column, presence: value over validates_presence_of.
validates_presence_of :<model_name>, unless: :

it basically converted this version

```
validates_presence_of :<model_name>, unless: :<condition>
```

To this:

```
validates :<model_name>, presence: { unless: :<condition> }
```